# AS3 - Create frame/screen within another frame/screen

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frame

I'm trying to create a menu system for a game.  I want to open different menu pages on the left side of the screen while the main game continues on the right.  Is there a way to overlay one frame over another in some way, or a better way to achieve this?  The best idea I have so far is to create all of the elements of each menu page all on the one frame, then add and remove the elements depending on which menu is called...but this sounds like a horrible way to go about it.  Example image of what I am trying to accomplish below:

[image: Example]

Thanks!

Comment: Just have your main game be its own MovieClip with it own nested timeline.  All the elements (or their parents at least) will need to be on the same frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with 2 movieclips. First MC represents the MENU and second MC represents the GAME, in the same frame. And from here you just have to make childs of each mc. Hope this idea help.

Comment: So obvious - I always miss the simple solution in favor of some convoluted round about way of doing it...Thank you!

Comment: It happens... :D All the best!